# Why the 6 in relu6?

Tags: tensorflow

I've hacked a deep feed forward NN from scratch in R, and it seems more stable with "hard sigmoid" activations - max(0,min(1,x)) - than ReLU. Trying to port it to TensorFlow, and noticed that they don't have this activation function built in, only relu6, which uses an upper cutoff at 6. Is there a reason for this? 
(I realize that you could do relu6(x*6)/6, but if the TF guys put the 6 there for a good reason, I'd like to know.)
Also, I'd like to know if others have explosion problems with ReLU in feed forward nets (I'm aware of RNN issues).

Answer (score 75, accepted):

From [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/3s65x8/tensorflow_relu6_minmaxfeatures_0_6/):

> This is useful in making the networks ready for fixed-point inference.
>   If you unbound the upper limit, you lose too many bits to the Q part
>   of a Q.f number. Keeping the ReLUs bounded by 6 will let them take a
>   max of 3 bits (upto 8) leaving 4/5 bits for .f

It seems, then, that 6 is just an arbitrary value chosen according to the number of bits you want to be able to compress your network's trained parameters into.
As per the "why" only the version with value 6 is implemented, I assume it's because that's the value that fits best in 8 bits, which probably is the most common use-case.

Answer (score 64):

Tensorflows documentation (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/relu6) points to the following paper:

> ... First, we cap the units at 6, so our ReLU activation
>   function is
>   y = min(max(x, 0), 6).
>   In our tests, this encourages the model to learn sparse features earlier. In the formulation of [8], this is
>   equivalent to imagining that each ReLU unit consists of only 6 replicated bias-shifted Bernoulli units, rather
>   than an infinute amount. We will refer to ReLU units capped at n as ReLU-n units.

http://www.cs.utoronto.ca/~kriz/conv-cifar10-aug2010.pdf

Since it originates from the paper, I suspect that they tested it with different n's and got the best results for their testset with n=6.

Comment: @MikhailVasilyev How does the other answer fit into the picture? Is the benefit in fixed-point inference simply a nice side effect? Or is it a secondary reason to choose relu6?

Comment: The number itself is arbitrary and is more of a scaling factor than anything else. What relu6 really does is give you a Z shape rather than a V shape, such that ReLU will max out beyond a certain distance from 0. This is the same behaviour you get from sigmoid and tanh. I suspect 6 was chosen as it roughly corresponds to sigmoid(6) == 0.997 which is roughly where sigmoid maxes out to be nearly 1.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a different number, for instance, if you are using hardcoded weights with binary data and want ReLU1() it can be implemented as follows:

```
class ReLU1(nn.Module):
    def forward(self, x):
        return F.relu6(x * 6.0) / 6.0
```

```
class ReLUX(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, max_value: float=1.0):
        super(ReLUX, self).__init__()
        self.max_value = float(max_value)
        self.scale     = 6.0/self.max_value

    def forward(self, x):
        return F.relu6(x * self.scale) / (self.scale)
```

Comment: I wanted to add spaces around `=` in the default value assignment, as the application of the newly introduced type hinting is "hidden away" with spaces around the colon, giving an immediate erroneous impression that the protected keyword `float` is set to 1 (and then called on `max_value`!). :-) But the proposed edit was too small. :-/